# What's the theory behind missing links in navigation?

Tags: 8

I know a lot of thinking has gone into D8's admin menu, but I'm clearly missing something. Some links don't seem to feature anywhere in the interface, and there seems a lack of consistency between bundle, entity listing and entity adding:

e.g.

- **Taxonomy** seems to be complete: there's a link in the admin menu to admin/structure/taxonomy and from there you can see the bundles (vocabularies), list the content (by bundle) or add content (in the drop-down link for the bundle).
- **Nodes** ("Content"): there's an admin menu entry for listing content, and one for content types, but there's no Add content item, either for node/add or for node/add/foo Are users expected to know to type this?
- **Custom blocks**: There's an admin link to the *types* of block, but no links to either the listing (`/admin/structure/block/block-content`) nor the links for adding any blocks?
- **Menus**: If a menu has no items there's an add item link on the listing page. Once you've added one item there is no link on the listing page (but you can still find it on the listing-of-menus page in the drop-down)

I realize I could make my own menu (e.g. I could manually add these missing links in where I want them, or I could use another module like shortcuts) but it feels like I shouldn't have to as these basic systems are unusable without internal technical knowledge about likely paths.

As I say, I know a lot of clever people have worked for years on D8, so I'm assuming I've missed something, or have something wrong with my D8 install?

Comment: For node/add, that is in the [_Tools_ block](http://d.pr/i/1gyTN).

Comment: OK, so I was missing the "tabs" and "primary action buttons". With these in place I have what I need for navigation. However, I've not posted this as an answer because I think the question stands: why aren't these basic necessities in the admin menu? Seems strange to mandate the use of a particular UI element (must all sites have tabs?)